# Is Halocarbons a subtag of halides?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I personally have the taste, that [halocarbons](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halocarbons) (6) is very specific and may be viewed as a subtopic of the more general [halides](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halides) (6). Incredibly, there is no cross tagging. I would merge the former tag into the latter.

Comment: I will defer to the experts on this one. If we get a couple of other opinions (yea/nay), I will take care of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing no objections, I have merged [halocarbons](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halocarbons) into [halides](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halides) and made [halocarbons](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halocarbons) a synonym of [halides](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halides).